# On Catalina, what should /private/tmp look like?

Tags: macos, catalina, symlink

This is my `/tmp` and `/private`:

```
# ls -lA /tmp /private/
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  admin  11 Oct 18 18:48 /tmp -> private/tmp

/private/:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  121 root  wheel  3872 Oct 21 13:27 etc
drwxr-xr-x    2 root  wheel    64 Aug 24 19:01 tftpboot
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root  wheel    11 Jul 26  2018 tmp -> private/tmp
drwxr-xr-x   29 root  wheel   928 Oct 21 08:08 var
#
```

This is on macOS 10.15.1 Catalina beta after restoring from a backup made during the early September beta of Catalina 10.15.0. The `tmp` file in `/private` appears to be a link to `private/tmp`, which doesn't exist. If it had a leading `/` it would be a circular reference to itself.

Two questions:

1. Should `/tmp` be a link to `/private/tmp` ?
2. (Assuming yes) What should `/private/tmp` actually be? A directory?

Thanks!

Comment: how did you fixed your issue of TMP being a circular reference to itself ?

Comment: It's been a while, but my memory is that I removed the errant link tmp from /private `rm /private/tmp` (as root, of course, possibly in a recovery console), and created a directory in its place `mkdir /private/tmp` and made sure the permissions matched, as much as possible, those in Scot's answer. The steps I took were successful. And I've moved on to a newer MBP since that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how my Catalina machine looks:

```
Charlie:/ sfederman$ ls -lA /tmp /private/
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  admin  11 Jul 16 14:05 /tmp -> private/tmp

/private/:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  86 root  wheel  2752 Oct 19 19:43 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    64 Jul  6 01:22 tftpboot
drwxrwxrwt   9 root  wheel   288 Oct 21 10:59 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  28 root  wheel   896 Oct  4 10:24 var
```

So:

1. Yes, `/tmp` is a softlink to `/private/tmp`
2. `/private/tmp` is a directory.

Comment: That fixed my other issues. Thank you!